# Unable to Locate Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, mean-stack

Sorry to be a pain, I can imagine this question has appeared in the past - but despite trying various different fixes - I'm still not getting anywhere.

So I've set up Node, NPM, Express on my current server based off instructions from this Youtube clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhPFgqHz68o

I've switched on my node server using
`node server/index.js`

Following this, in a new tab in my terminal I used `cd server` then `npm install` which then produced the following: 
`npm WARN package.json MeanApp@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json MeanApp@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json MeanApp@1.0.0 No README data`

I then ran `npm install grunt --save-dev`, which then produced the following: `npm WARN package.json MeanApp@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json MeanApp@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json MeanApp@1.0.0 No README data
grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
├── which@1.0.9
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.1.22
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── exit@0.1.2
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.1)
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1 (underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.1)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (esprima@1.0.4, argparse@0.1.16)`

Following this, I then ran `grunt server` which produced: A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started guide for
more information on how to configure grunt: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.

However, I've looked inside my server folder on my computer and it contains grunt, inside node-modules > grunt > lib > grunt.js

Please help, I'm driving myself crazy.

Comment: Try update npm?

npm update

Comment: Tried that already, but not get anywhere which is frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

When you run `grunt serve` Grunt is looking for a file in the root directory called `Gruntfile.js`, this file is where you write all your Grunt tasks.

The file you found inside `node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js` is actually Grunt itself.

I recommend taking a read of the [Getting Started guide that Grunt provides](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started), it'll give you a clear idea of how to get set up correctly with Grunt and how to combine it with your project.